# How can I convert C++ lambda function code to C#?

Tags: c#, c++

I have a C++ code, like:

```
const auto Func = [](int& x, const int& y) 
{
    x += y;
};
```

and using it like this:

`Func(a, b);`

I have not seen [] as function names.

How can I convert this C++ code to C#?

Comment: `FnName = [ ]( args ) { }` is called a lambda function.

Comment: based on your question: I have found that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx denotes this as a lambda "expression". hence lambda expression c# is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions. possibly (x,y) => x == y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other said, it is called a lambda expressions, and it was introduced in C++11. You can easily convert it in C#, but I don't think that lambda expression is very useful.

In C#, in the class definition (outside a method), or even outside the class definition:

```
delegate void VoidRefInt32RefInt32(ref int x, ref int y);
```

then, inside a method:

```
VoidRefInt32RefInt32 func = (ref int x, ref int y) => x += y;

int i1 = 1;
int i2 = 2;
func(ref i1, ref i2);
Console.WriteLine(i1);
```

But it is something quite useless... and `ref int y` could simply be `int y`, like:

```
delegate void VoidRefInt32Int32(ref int x, int y);
```

and then

```
VoidRefInt32Int32 func = (ref int x, int y) => x += y;

int i1 = 1;
int i2 = 2;
func(ref i1, i2);
Console.WriteLine(i1);
```

And it still would be quite useless...

Note that `Func<,>` is incompatible with `ref`, so we have to define a custom delegate (the `delegate void ...` part)

Comment: OK, problem resolved. thank you very much, thanks for all!